# How to toggle auto detect checkbox in Windws 8 LAN Settings

Tags: windows, batch-file, networking, lan

I was able to toggle my proxy settings using a bat script like so...

```
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" ^
    /v ProxyEnable /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
netsh wlan connect name=foo
```

but I am really want to toggle the "Automatically detect settings" to off in this script as well (back on in another "no proxy" script. Any ideas?

[LAN Settings GUI](http://shaneofalltrades.com/images-for-online-stuff/detect-settings.JPG)
[image]

Answer (score -1):

I think:

```
reg add "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings" /v AutoDetect /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
```

ticks the box and change the one to a 0 for 'disable' or un-tick